# UIWebView initwithFrame crash my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

1) I declared `UIWebView` as a property with strong attribute (strong) called `webView`;

2) In `viewDidLoad` method I am checking if my web constant exists or not. Based on that I will create with implicit constant of my webView property called `_webView`;

3) Then `[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:]` give to my `_webView`;

4) Finally sometimes it crashes on iOS 8 or iOS 9 or iOS7 platform with the picture i post here from Fabric CrashReport;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setBaseNaviBarInfo];

    if (_webInfoDictionary.count > 0) {
        NSString *titile = [_webInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"activityName"];
        [self setNaviItemText:titile];
    }

    [self createViews];
    CLS_LOG(@"init create wb view ......");

    NSString* url = [_webInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"activityLink"];
    [self loadWebViewWithURLString:url];
}

-(void)createViews{
    if (!_webView) {
        //Crash Now
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, STATUS_NAVI_STATUS_HEIGHT, IPHONE_WIDTH, IPHONE_HEIGHT - STATUS_NAVI_STATUS_HEIGHT)];

        _webView.delegate = self;
        _webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
        _webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
        [self.view addSubview:_webView];

        _activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)] ;
        [_activityIndicatorView setCenter: self.view.center] ;
        [_activityIndicatorView setActivityIndicatorViewStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] ;
        [self.view addSubview : _activityIndicatorView];
    }
}
```

[Crash Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foqym.png)

Comment: try calling it in viewdidappear

Comment: paste some code. How do you create your webview? IBOutlet? How do you handle that in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Update your question with your `viewDidLoad` and `createViews` methods.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated, Thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: @RamarajT Posted now , please help me re-check it, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. The code should work fine unless you had some weird values in the constants. Anyway try this _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] instead of hard coding the values, use the bounds of the view.